# How Can I Allow Website to Access Local File System in CEFSharp WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium, cefsharp

I'm writing a wpf app with an integrated CEFSharp webbrowser control, and I've hit a snag on a website. This website needs access to the local file system, but I'm not sure how or where to catch this on the backend and grant access. I've implemented IRequestHandler and IResourceRequestHandler, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Here's the error from the website:
[image]

[image]

Somehow, Chrome catches and handles it:

[image]

I would like to handle it in a similar fashion. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestHandler_OnQuotaRequest.htm

Comment: @amaitland, you are correct, that I should catch this in the OnQuotaRequest method, and I've written the "callback.Continue(true)", followed by "return true", but I still get the same error. Is there something else that I should be doing here?

Comment: Nevermind, this worked perfectly the second time that I ran it! Not sure why it didn't work the first time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @amaitland and @Jimenemex for your responses. They really did get me going in the right direction. In the end, I needed to catch the file system request in the IRequestHandler's "OnQuotaRequest" event. The following code solved my issue:

```
public bool OnQuotaRequest(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, long newSize,
        IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        string askingURL = Helper.GetWebsiteName(originUrl);
        var infoWindow = new InformationWindow("", "Allow " + askingURL, "to store files on this device?");
        infoWindow.OkButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        infoWindow.YesButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        infoWindow.NoButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        infoWindow.Topmost = true;

        if (infoWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            callback.Continue(true);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-requestFileSystem) on the Chrome browser correctly, it seems as if Chromium is calling `chrome.fileSystem.requestFileSystem(object options, function callback)` automatically.

I would think if you want to handle this manually, you would need too prompt the user for this permission/action, meaning  do that same API call from inside the Chromium client in CEFSharp.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this on the backend. Would you happen to have an example? I might need to implement this in my response to the "OnQuotaRequest" method.

Comment: I was able to fix this in the OnQuotaRequest method in the IRequestHandler in CEFSharp. I'm assuming that this automatically calls the "fileSystem.requestFileSystem(object options, function callback)" when you return true;